# Terminal read command - read an INT Number and only allow keys +- 0-9

Tags: bash, ansi-escape

I'm a new Linux and Bash user.
I wanted to read an INT Number by keyboard input with the read command,
but allowing only keys +- at first position and the number keys 0-9, i also need the
same for FLOAT Numbers.

I wrote a BASH function, but i'm now asking myself and especially you, if there is not a simplier way.

```
#!/bin/bash

#-- read out the keystroke repeat rate and calculate the sampling time to get inside the key interval time for one key
#-- to be sure to produce at least one read(command) time out failure to recognize when an ANSI ESCAPE code sequence ends
declare read_samplingTime keystroke_RepeatRate=$(xset -q | grep "repeat rate")
keystroke_RepeatRate=${keystroke_RepeatRate#*rate:}
read_samplingTime=$(bc <<<"scale=5; x=1/(2*$keystroke_RepeatRate); print 0; x")

function read_INTNumber ()
    {
    #-- inputSTR .. holds the accepted characters for the number (+|- 0-9), key .. the actual key(ASCII char), AESCcode .. ANSI ESCAPE code (a row of ASCII decimal), when pressed an arrow, page down or ..
    #-- keyCode .. the ASCII char decimal value for the key, posCursor .. position Cursor, bAESCsequence .. Boolean to indicate an AESCsequence started
    local inputSTR="" key="" AESCcode=""
    local -i keyCode=-1 posCursor=0  bAESCsequence=0
    
    #-- stop if enter is hit KeyCode 10
    until [[ $keyCode -eq 10 ]]
        do
        read -sn 1 -t $read_samplingTime key
        #--check for time out failure, in exit status of read
        if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
            #-- hiting enter will stop the reading of one character, leaving an empty null string in key
            #-- so set keyCode to 10 manually; for other keys printf produces the keyCode
            if [[ $key == "" ]]; then keyCode=10
            else printf -v keyCode "%d" "'$key"; fi
            
            #-- During AESCsequence add keyCode to AESCcode
            if [[ bAESCsequence -eq 1 ]]; then AESCcode+=" $keyCode"
            else
                #-- numbers 0-9
                if ((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <=57)); then inputSTR+=$key; echo -n "$key"; ((posCursor++))
                else
                    case $keyCode in
                        #-- AESC sequence started
                        27)    bAESCsequence=1; AESCcode="27";;
                        #-- backspace - dont allow at cursor position 0
                        8)     if [[ posCursor -gt 0 ]]; then inputSTR=${inputSTR:0:-1}; echo -n "$key $key"; ((posCursor --)); fi;;
                        #-- +- at cursor position 0
                        43|45) if [[ posCursor -eq 0 ]]; then inputSTR+=$key; echo -n "$key"; ((posCursor++)); fi;;
                    esac
                fi
            fi
        elif [[ bAESCsequence -eq 1 ]];
            #-- read exited with a time out failure, so check if last key started a bAESCsequence, if so this, sequence already ended,
            then echo $AESCcode; AESCcode="", bAESCsequence=0;
        fi
        done
    }
    
read_INTNumber
```

and if there is not a simplier way, i need also some editing functionality like backspace, delete, POS-1, POS-END, left|right arrow.

for these keys i get an ANSI ESCAPE sequence (row of ASCII decimal)
for example in the gnome terminal:

- left arrow ....27 91 68
- right arrow ...27 91 68
- POS-1 .........27 91 72
- POS-2 .........27 91 70

Are these codes for keyboard keys always the same in each terminal, or at least in the most terminals? - because there also ANSI ESCAPE CODES to set colors but they are different in other terminals

thx in advance

EDIT 22.02.2024: to read a key from keyboard, i now use this

```
#!/bin/bash
declare readKey_samplingTime #-- the max period time for reading a key, needed to find an ANSI Escape Code Sequence end
#-- read out the keystroke repeat rate and calculate the sampling time to get inside the key sending interval time for one key,
#-- to be sure to produce at least one read(command) time out failure to recognize, when an ANSI Escape Code Sequence ends
readKey_samplingTime=$(xset -q | grep "repeat rate")
readKey_samplingTime=${readKey_samplingTime#*rate: };                              #-- readKey_samplingTime is containing key stroke repeat rate
[[ readKey_samplingTime =~ [0-9]+ ]] || readKey_samplingTime=25                    #-- check if value is an integer, if not set key stroke repeat rate to 25
readKey_samplingTime=$(bc <<<"scale=3; x=1/(2*$readKey_samplingTime); print 0; x") #-- calculate the sampling time by doubling the key stroke repeat rate, to get inside the key sending interval time
#-- condition for success: the read loop execution time must be faster than the sampling time -> execution time + sampling time < key sending interval time -> to get a read time out error

#-- call:        readKey [break keyCode STR]
#-- description: reads the pressed key and converts it to an extended ASCII char keyCode(decimal) or to an ANSI Escape Code Sequence(a series of keyCode decimals, separated by space).
#--              calls readKey_action with
#--                1) extended ASCII char keyCode: readKey_action $key $keyCode
#--                2) ANSI Escape Code Sequence:   readKey_action "" $AESCcode
#--              If we have an ANSI Escape Code Sequence, $1 the actual key in readKey_action is "".
#-- parameters:  $1 ... break keyCode STR - The extended ASCII keyCode or the ANSI Escape Code Sequence, when to stop reading.
#-- depends on:  variables - readKey_samplingTime; functions - readKey_action
readKey ()
   {
   #-- key            ... the actual key (UTF-8 char) or a part of an ANSI Escape Sequence ( \e or [ or ..)
   #-- keyCode        ... the extended ASCII char decimal value for the key or for the ANSI Escape Sequence part
   #-- isAESCsequence ... boolean to indicate an AESCsequence started
   #-- AESCcode       ... ANSI Escape code (a series of ASCII decimal), when pressed an arrow, page down or ..
   local key="" AESCcode=""
   local -i keyCode=-1 isAESCsequence=0

   stty -echo #-- turn terminal echo off
   while :; do
      read -N 1 -r -t $readKey_samplingTime key
      #--check for time out failure, in exit status of read
      if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
         printf -v keyCode "%d" "'$key"
         #-- During AESCsequence add keyCode to AESCcode
         if ((isAESCsequence)); then AESCcode+=" $keyCode"
         else
            if [[ $keyCode == "$1" ]]; then break; fi                                            #-- break loop
            if (( $keyCode == 27 || $keyCode == 91 )); then isAESCsequence=1; AESCcode=$keyCode  #-- $'\e' or "[" starts an ANSI escape sequence, because sometimes \e gets lost during keystroke repeat
            else readKey_action "$key" "$keyCode"                                                #-- call readKey_action
            fi
         fi
       #-- read exited with a time out failure, so check if last key started a AESCsequence, if so this sequence already ended.
      elif ((isAESCsequence)); then
         #-- "[" started an ANSI escape sequence, but it was no ANSI escape sequence, it was just the normal "[" key, because the code contains only 91, so call readKey_action, as it was the normal [ key
         if [[ $AESCcode == "91" ]]; then
            if [[ $1 == "91" ]]; then break                                                      #-- break loop
            else readKey_action "$key" "$keyCode"                                                #-- call readKey_action
            fi
         else
            if [[ ${AESCcode%% *} == "91" ]]; then AESCcode="27 "$AESCcode; fi                   #-- "[" started an ANSI escape sequence, add 27 for $'\e'
            if [[ $AESCcode == "$1" ]]; then break; fi                                           #-- break loop
            readKey_action "" "$AESCcode"                                                        #-- call readKey_action
         fi
         AESCcode=""; isAESCsequence=0
      fi
   done
   stty echo #-- turn terminal echo on
   }

#-- is called:   readKey_action [key STR] [keyCode STR]
#-- description: Is called from function readKey and can combine keys with actions.
#--              In this example, it's just printing out the key and the keyCode or the keyCode sequence for the pressed key.
#-- parameters:  $1 ... The actual key (UTF8).
#--              $2 ... The actual extended ASCII char keyCode or an ANSI Escape Code Sequence.
#--                     If we have an ANSI Escape Code Sequence, $1 the actual key is "".
#-- depends on:  functions - readKey
readKey_action ()
   {
   echo "key: '$1'; keyCode: '$2'"
   }
   
readKey "10"  #-- example - stop at hitting return
```

Comment: Why not just use `read -e`, and let bash's built-in readline feature handle editing? You can use `bind` to adjust its response to various key sequences.

Comment: i read about bind, but how do you get control over the cursor position with read -e - lets say you want to allow plus minus only at first, position - or for float values allow only one dot? just check the whole value after the user hits enter and then prompt, wrong number, reenter input?

Comment: Yep, that'd be the usual way. Trying to implement your own readline-like interface in bash seems a bit like trying to teach a horse to play checkers -- it's going to be a lot of work, and I doubt the result'll be very good.

Comment: "to teach a horse to play checkers" i fear you are right. i already did a simple test in terminal - while true; do read -n 1 -st 0.0001 char ;done -  the option read -s (do not echo input coming from terminal) is not working correctly, if combined with -t and a very low timeout value (< 0.01s) , if i hold down a key for longer time, the terminal echos some characters, which it shouldnt, is this a known bug?

Comment: They're probably getting echoed because they happened to be received in the interval between `read`s. See [this Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/671455/silent-option-for-read-gets-ignored).

Comment: great - your answer in the link!!  i removed the -s option from read and insert stty -echo in my script before the until loop and after the loop ends i inserted stty echo to turn the terminal echo on again, now it works correctly, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, these are ANSI escape sequences https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_(Control_Sequence_Introducer)_sequences .

- 27 = 0x1b = CSI
- 91 = 0x5b = [
- 68 = 0x44 = C
- 67 = 0x43 = D
- right arrow = CSI [ C
- left arrow  = CSI [ D

> Are these codes for keyboard keys always the same in each terminal

No. There are so many terminals and virtual terminals. [Terminfo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminfo).

> , or at least in the most terminals?

Nowadays universally yes.

> because there also ANSI ESCAPE CODES to set colors but they are different in other terminals

That would be odd, [8-bit ones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors) surely are the same everywhere.

Comment: thx for the answer, cant give it an upvote, too few points - how do you check for a number, check the whole value after the user hits enter and then ask for retyping?

Comment: `how do you check for a number, check the whole value after the user hits enter and then ask for retyping?` usually, yes, it's the simplest. like `read -p 'plaese give a number  ' -r number; if [[ ! "$number" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then echo try again ...; fi`

Comment: thx, i think i'll choose your way, because i already did a simple test in terminal - while true; do read -n 1 -st 0.0001 char ;done - the option read -s (do not echo input coming from terminal) is not working correctly, if combined with -t and a very low timeout value (< 0.01s) , if i hold down a key for longer time, the terminal echos some characters, which it shouldnt, is this a known bug?   with that in background, i cant implement a correct editing. thx for your time

Comment: already answered by Gordon Davisson above, thx